# Python turtle error on closing screen - code from How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.5, turtle-graphics

when I run this code

```
import turtle
import time

def show_poly():
    try:
        win = turtle.Screen()
        tess = turtle.Turtle()
        n = int(input("How many sides do you want in your polygon?"))
        angle = 360 / n
        for i in range(n):
            tess.forward(10)
            tess.left(angle)
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        win.bye()

show_poly()
show_poly()
show_poly()
```

I get the first call work properly than I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "/home/turte.py", line 19,
>       in  show_poly()
>
> File "/home/turte.py", line 8, in show_poly
>       tess = turtle.Turtle()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 3816, in **init**
>       visible=visible)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 2557, in **init**
>       self._update()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
>       self._update_data()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
>       self.screen._incrementudc()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
>
> raise Terminator turtle.Terminator

If I understand the problem I cannot create a new screen even if I closed the last.
I run python 3.5

Comment: Your code raises `SyntaxError` here.

Comment: Sorry It was an indentation error. Moreover It works on Python3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `turtle.Screen()` is intended to be a singleton so your code is actively fighting the module design. Accourding to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) you should be using an instance of `RawTurtle` in applications.

```
import turtle
import time
import tkinter as tk


def show_poly():
    try:
        n = int(input("How many sides do you want in your polygon?"))
        angle = 360 / n
        root = tk.Tk()
        canvas = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        tess = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
        for i in range(n):
            tess.forward(10)
            tess.left(angle)
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        root.destroy()


show_poly()
show_poly()
show_poly()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I read the singleton stuff from the doc but since I found this code on "How to Think Like a Computer
Scientist: Learning with Python 3" I didn't understand where really was the problem. 
Moreover It works on python 3.4 but not on 3.5 or 2.7.

Comment: That was a poor choice by the author. If the return value of `Screen()` is a singleton I would consider its behavior after `.bye()` undefined. It might work by chance but you should not rely on that. I have found `tkinter` being a bit sctricter in recent releases, there are some other undocumented tricks that do not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to work within turtle and avoid tkinter when possible.  In the following solution, instead of destroying the window and making a new one, we simply clear it and draw anew:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from time import sleep

def show_poly(turtle):
    n = 0

    while n < 3:
        try:
            n = int(input("How many sides do you want in your polygon? "))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    angle = 360 / n

    for _ in range(n):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(angle)

    sleep(3)
    turtle.clear()

window = Screen()

tess = Turtle()

show_poly(tess)
show_poly(tess)
show_poly(tess)

window.bye()
```

This should also be compatible with both Python 2.7 and Python 3